# ¿Cómo actualizar datos de la base de datos desde .net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tengo un `form` que es para actualizar dos tablas `empleados`(se actualiza email y teléfono) y `usuarios`(actualiza la contraseña)

La cuestión es ¿Cómo actualizar esta información?

Este es el codigo del `CuentaController`

```
public ActionResult ModificarCuentaEmp(empleados e)
    {
        int idEmp = Convert.ToInt32(Session["idEmp"]);
        int tipoUsu = Convert.ToInt32(Session["tipoUsu"]);

        ViewBag.idemp = idEmp;
        ViewBag.tipousu = tipoUsu;

        if (tipoUsu == 1)
        {
            ViewBag.tusu = "Administrador";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.tusu = "Empleado";
        }

        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (DbModel db = new DbModel())
                {

                        var em = db.empleados.Where(a => a.id_Emp.Equals(idEmp)).FirstOrDefault();
                        db.Entry(em).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();


                    TempData["ConfirmationMessage"] = "Datos actualizados";
                    return RedirectToAction("MiCuenta");

                }

            }



        }
        catch
        {
            TempData["ConfirmationMessage"] = "Error al actualizar los datos ";
            return RedirectToAction("MiCuenta");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("MiCuenta");
    }
```

Codigo de la vista  `Mi Cuenta`:

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
            <div class="white-box">
                <h3 class="box-title">DATOS</h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ModificarCuentaEmp", "Cuenta", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
                <div class="comment-center p-t-10">
                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-8">
                              @* @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.nombre_Emp, new { placeholder = "Nombre(s)", @style = "text-transform:uppercase" })*@
                               <label>Nombre</label><br />
                               <label style="color:deepskyblue">@ViewBag.nomcomp&#160;</label><br/>
                                   <label>Email</label><br />
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.correo_Emp, new {value=@ViewBag.email, @class="form-control"})<br/>
                                   <label>Contraseña Actual</label><br />
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.usuarios.contraseña_Usu, new { value = @ViewBag.pass, @class="form-control"})<br />
                                   <label>Teléfono</label><br />
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.telefono_Emp, new { value = @ViewBag.tel, @class="form-control"})
                               </div>
                    </div>
                        <center><button class="btn btn-success">Guardar Cambios</button></center>
                            </form>
                         </div>

}
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 2):

Aqui obtienes el formulario donde mostrarás la información.

```
[HttGet]
public ActionResult ModificarCuentaEmp()
{ 
 ...
}
```

y el siguiente es el que te hace falta:

```
[HttPost]
public ActionResult ModificarCuentaEmp(empleados e)
{ 
 ...
}
```

Nótese el uso de los decoradores HttpGet y HttPost, en caso no los utilices, by default se comporta como un GET, motivo por el cual no puedes guardar (ActionResult inexistente)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ModificarCuentaEmp", "Cuenta", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Hace un tiempo hice un workshop sobre ASP.net MVC (desde cero) espero te sea de utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY